# How to integrate $\frac{x^n\,\,\,\sqrt{x+1} }{\left(m (x+1)^3-x\right)^{3/2}}$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let 
$$
f(x)=\frac{x^n\,\,\,\sqrt{x+1} }{\left(m (x+1)^3-x\right)^{3/2}}
$$

$$
0<m<\frac{4}{27}\,\,\,\,;\,\,\,\frac{1}{2}<n<1
$$

I am trying to integrate the above function. I tried several methods that I know. I also used Mathematica to integrate the function however I wasn't able to find a solution.

Does anyone know how to integrate $f(x)$ with respect to x.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you searching for antiderivative? (Indefinite integral)

Comment: Yes, but an integration from $x_{0}$ to $\infty$, where $x_{0}$ is some constant, would be helpful too.

Comment: Are $n,m$ integers? Or arbitrary positive real numbers?

Comment: @You'reInMyEye, $m$ and $n$ are arbitrary positive real numbers and $n$ is less than $1$.

Comment: I tried for $n=1$ and $m=0.1$ (just as an example). Mathematica gives a very complicated expression in terms of Elliptic Integrals. From this we can assume that the general expression for $m,n$ is even more complicated.

Comment: @You'reInMyEye, Yes I got similar result.